# Searching in elastic search by a routing key providing data of another routing key also

Tags: elasticsearch

When I am searching in elastic search by a routing key, it is also returning result of another routing key.

Path:Index_2022/_search?routing=10

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5000,
    "timeout": "15m",
    "query":
    {
        "bool":
        {
            "must":
            [
                {
                    "query_string":
                    {
                        "query": "*",
                        "fields":
                        [
                            "content^1.0"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am searching result with routing key 10, but elastic gives result of routing key 3 also.

Comment: can you share sample documents, also provide your search results which shows that its returning results of `3`

Comment: Search result {
    "_index": "index_2022",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "sg3c8x",
    "_score": 1,
    "_routing": "3",
    "_source": {
     "data_hash": "sg3c8x",
     "content": "this is a doc",
    }
   },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of the routing key is only to define in which shard the document is going to be stored. The value of the [routing key is hashed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/mapping-routing-field.html) and the result is a shard index.

If you have 1M documents and 4 shards then each of your shard is going to contain approximately ~250K documents. All those documents might have different routing keys, but their hash always resolves to the number of primary shards (i.e. 0, 1, 2 and 3).

So in your case, the documents having routing keys 10 and 3 have a hash that both resolve to the same primary shard index, which is why you're finding them in the same shard.

The idea behind searching with a routing key is to search inside a fewer amount of shards. Say you have 4 shards and you know that what you're searching for has a routing key of 10 (e.g. it could be a tenant id, a customer id, etc), so you specify `routing=10` and then the search will only happen inside a single shard instead of searching through all 4 shards, which usually yields faster query response time.

Comment: But My question is that I am using custom routing, at the timing of writing each document I am passing routing key. So when I searching document with routing key 10 why I am getting documents  with routing key 3

Comment: Because you search for "*", so all documents match and since you're routing your query to the shard with routing=10, that shard might also contain documents with other routing keys whose hash resolve to the same shard. The routing key is not a search criteria, it's just a hint for ES to know where (i.e. on which shard) to run your search query.